# Change value of several records at once (field is boolean type)

Tags: ms-access, keyboard-shortcuts, ms-access-2007

Today I got stuck with something in Access. Can't find a **keyboard solution**.

Here's the problem.  Got a query where first field is a Yes/no field:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I can move between records using arrows in keyboard, and activate/deactivate value with SPACE key

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

It can be done too with mouse and left click, of course. My question is: ¿Is there any shortcut key or key binding or something to activate/deactivate several records at once? I don't want to go one by one, pressing space, next. Already got a macro to activate/deactivate all of them at once, but sometimes I just need 7 or 3 or 13, not just one or all.

Example. I select 4 records:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

If I press <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, it does nothing. I would like to know what keys do I have to use to get it done like this:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

It would be something similar to drag and fill in Excel, but applied to Access.

Maybe it just can't be done, I don't know, that's why I'm asking this here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @June7 Did not found that answer, looked up for "records" instead of rows. Let me try some of them and see If I can get a workaround. Thanks!!!!!